# Activity not rendering layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

the new activity is not displaying any layout on intending a new activity . if I use this -

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}
```

but when i removed `PersistableBundle persistentState` from `onCreate` Method layout is rendered to a new activity. Can anyone explain this??

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: you obviously should not use this method. There is another `onCreate` overload with 1 parameter. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // this method sets the layout for your activity
        // main.xml should be defined in your layout folder
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
}
```